# Add or subtract rows in a pandas column depending on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this script:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([["a",10],["a",15],["b",16],["a",11],["b",12],["b",14],["b",17],
                  ["b",19],["a",10]], columns=["col1","col2"])
```

which gives the following output:

```
  col1 col2
0   a   10
1   a   15
2   b   16
3   a   11
4   b   12
5   b   14
6   b   17
7   b   19
8   a   10
```

In the meantime I have a variable (starting balance) equal to 1000. Whenever there is "a" in col1 I want to increase the starting balance by the value in col2; whenever there is "b" in col1 I want to decrease the accumulated balance by the value in col2. So expected result is:

1000+10+15-16+11-12-14-17-19+10=968 .

If possible I want to also create a column "balance" where at each point/step I see the resulting balance.

```
    col1    col2    balance
0    a       10      1010
1    a       15      1025
2    b       16      1009
3    a       11      1020
4    b       12      1008
5    b       14      994
6    b       17      977
7    b       19      958
8    a       10      968
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can conditionally assign a sign with `np.where` and then use `cumsum`:

```
(np.where(df['col1'] == 'a', 1, -1) * df['col2']).cumsum() + 1000

0    1010
1    1025
2    1009
3    1020
4    1008
5     994
6     977
7     958
8     968
Name: col2, dtype: int64
```

Same idea, instead using `map`:

```
df['col1'].map({'a': 1, 'b': -1}).mul(df['col2']).cumsum().add(1000)

0    1010
1    1025
2    1009
3    1020
4    1008
5     994
6     977
7     958
8     968
Name: col2, dtype: int64
```

The advantage of `map` is that the output is a Series (as opposed to `where` which returns a numpy array) so this naturally lends itself to method chaining a bit more nicely. However, `where` is a shade faster (because, numpy).

Answer (score 2):

**Same solutions**

```
df1['Balance'] = df_.col1.map({'a': 1 , 'b':-1}) * df1.col2.cumsum() + 1000
print(df1)

 col1  col2  Balance
0    a    10  1010
1    a    15  1025
2    b    16  1009
3    a    11  1020
4    b    12  1008
5    b    14   994
6    b    17   977
7    b    19   958
8    a    10   968
```

Comment: Please do not blatantly post identical solutions to other answers posted minutes before yours.

Comment: it happened to be same, did not deliberate it

Comment: Your post literally said "Same solution as above in multiple steps" when you posted it, you wouldn't have known it was the same unless you'd seen my answer already.

Comment: sir as i was about to post my solution , it looked same so had to say that @cs95

Comment: Just as a friendly reminder, please be mindful of duplicating other answers... if yours was posted within a few seconds of theirs, that's fine, otherwise please consider either changing your answer, improving it, or removing it altogether.

Comment: okay, yes it got duplicated but was snot copied , will take care thnx